# Javascript generating a random Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)

Tags: javascript, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to write a function to generate a random Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) with n nodes. I wrote this function to generate nodes now I need to generate the edges, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I have some constraints, the graph is acyclic and a node can have a maximum of 3 parents.

```
var colors = ["#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF"]
var alpahbet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

var intializeNodes = function (numOfNodes){
    for(i = 0; i< numOfNodes; i++){
        nodes.push({
            group: 'nodes',
            data: {id: alpahbet.charAt(i), color: colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]},
        });
        nodes.push()
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: OK, so you've created some nodes.  What have you tried in the way of creating edges?

Comment: I don't think that it is as easy as adding all nodes at once and then adding some edges. You have to prevent isolated nodes and maintain the max number of child nodes. I think I read a paper about DAG-generation with the Markov Chain. If you can, read up on the current approaches to implement random DAG-Generation, i found several interesting articles.

Comment: Depending on the size required, it might be simple enough to randomly add edges, checking for each that the graph remains acyclic and there are no more than the maximum inbound nodes on the target.  It would probably become problematic if the number of edges grows too close to the maximum possible, but if we're not close to that, it's probably the simplest technique.  Alternately, add all potential edges and repeatedly remove random ones until the criteria is met.

Comment: Eeeh, random means that there can be pretty weired results. If you want to make sure you match the criteria, I don't think it is as easy as just adding some edges and hoping the removal of some makes the graph acyclic. There are already 26 nodes with at least probably 2 to 5 outgoing edges.